# REST API concat in OIC giving extra character

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, fusion, cloud-integration

I am calling a REST API:
[https://abc.oracle.ocs.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?q=PersonNumber='4'](https://abc.oracle.ocs.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?q=PersonNumber=%274%27)

[image]

But this is not building the URL correctly and the response I am getting is :

https://abc.oracle.ocs.oraclecloud.com:443/hcmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/workers?Q=PersonNumber%3D4

This extra "%3" is coming up instead of "=". Concat function should be used differently, any suggestions ?

Comment: Is concat doing that, or is the value being encoded later? `q=PersonNumber='4'` looks odd - encoding the `=` that's part of the query value doesn't seem unreasonable, but I guess it's how it's handled at the far end that matters. Maybe.

Comment: i am not sure, it seems "=" is being encoded to  "%3D" Later as i can see that in the response. The end point url is working fine when I am using Postman and calling this end point